# Where in TortoiseHG to set a login and password for accessing the remote repository?

Tags: tortoisehg

They threw the way to the repository, login and password. I enter the browser normally, I see everything.
In TortoiseHG, when I try to clone the repository, I get an error:

does not appear to be an hg repository

Win10

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL that you enter into TortoiseHg.

Most likely, the URL that works in web browser leads to the repository web interface. However, in Hg client you should enter the URL to repository, not to the web UI.